# "python: can't open file" error when running docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, import

I wrote a simple Python script called **myscript.py**, calling a custom module in **mycustommodules**.
Below is my folder structure:

```
-docker-compose.yml
-Dockerfile
-mycustommodules
    |
    -config.py
    -__init__.py
-mysubfolder
    |
    -acquisition
        |
        -myscript.py
```

When I call the script from the terminal it runs correctly.
However, running `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose up --build` installs the specified Python packages but then returns the following error:

```
rta-app2_1  | python: can't open file 'mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8.3
ADD ./mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py .
ADD mycustommodules .
RUN pip install h5py datetime argparse 
CMD ["python", "mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py"]
```

I tried replacing the last line with `CMD ["python", "./mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py"]` , to no avail.

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

Here is **myscript.py**:

```
import serial
import threading
import queue 
import struct
import sys
import os
import h5py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import subprocess
import re
import argparse
from shutil import move
sys.path.append("/media/sheldon/My Passport/docker_rta_experiment")
from mycustommodules import config

def main_run():
    print("OK MAIN_RUN WAS CALLED SUCCESSFULLY")
    print(config.example_config_parameter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("AHOY!")
    try:
        main_run()
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
```

The **config.py** simply contains:

```
example_config_parameter = 42
```

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rta-app2:
    build:
      context: .
```

The script should output:

> ```
> AHOY!
> OK MAIN_RUN WAS CALLED SUCCESSFULLY
> 42
> ```

Comment: `ADD ./mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py .` I'm not sure this is duplicating the entire subdirectory structure.  I think it may simply be copying `myscript.py` straight into the current directory.

Comment: To check this, you should be able to use `docker exec` to open a shell inside the container and see what directories actually exist.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @JohnGordon. I will try SSHing into the container as per your suggestion.

Comment: `ADD ./mysubfolder/acquisition/myscript.py .` this only copies `myscript.py` into current workdir.  "I will try SSHing into the container as per your suggestion" docker exec is not ssh.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification @erik258. I tried accessing the container's shell using `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` but got this message: `Error response from daemon: Container xxx is not running`.